# How do you do an 'and' condition?

Tags: regex

I need a regex expression, where a string starts with test and contains xyz, I have tried:

```
(?=^Test)(?=xyz)
```

How do you do an 'and' condition in a regular expression?

Comment: `(?s)^Test.*xyz`. BTW, what is the regex flavor?

Comment: [`^test.*?xyz`](https://regex101.com/r/tK1pY4/1)

Comment: Thanks, how would I add an or? E.g. start with test AND (contains xyz OR abc)

Comment: `^test.*(xyz|abc)`

Comment: @panthro: There is no clear answer now. `.*` matches zero or more  any characters but a newline, so `^Test.*xyz` will match `Test` at the start AND up to the last `xyz` on the same line. when you write `(?=^Test)(?=xyz)`, you already use AND: you require the string to start with `Test`, and that there is `xyz` right at the same position - thus, it will always fail. If you need your own regex, you can use `(?=^Test)(?=.*xyz)`, but it is inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Using your example it would be: (?=.*Test)(?=.*xyz)
This says that test must appear anywhere and xyz must appear anywhere, not necessarily in that order and possibly overlapping

Comment: No, this is not checking if `Test` is at the start of the string. If `xyz` is on the second line, the regex will fail, too.

Comment: Ahh! So then you just need n [start(n),end(n)] group(n)

Comment: No, we need to know what regex flavor OP uses, and what OP needs to achieve.

Comment: Agree with the engine part (or flavor as you call it) but I think the OP question is straight forward

Comment: It is not straight-forward because there is no "AND" in regex. Combining two regex patterns can be done differently depending on these patterns and the goal.

Comment: Ok, I agree :-) didn't think about it that way